# Gson parse json where each field is an object

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have json like that:

```
"fields": [
    [
        {
            "id": "11111"
        },
        {
            "name": "dsfafds"
        },
        {
            "description": "sdfadfas"
        }
     ],
     ]   
        {
            "id": "11111"
        },
        {
            "name": "dsfafds"
        },
        {
            "description": "sdfadfas"
        }
     ],

       ........
```

So each field is an object, is there an easy way to parse it to object like:

```
class Json {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    ......
}
```

I know about gson adapters, but I would like to reduce the source code, maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: Despite the fact that you did not post the entire JSON string I can not believe that the JSON structure you posted would be valid. ""fields": [
    [
        {" makes no sense.

Comment: @Barns I have edited json, it is valid json

Comment: Why have a Json array within another json array??

Comment: I don't know. Maybe it is some legacy code.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need something like this too.

```
public class Example {

private List<Json> fields = null;

public List<Json> getFields() {
    return fields;
}

public void setFields(List<Json> fields) {
    this.fields = fields;
}

}
```

[Json to Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) is a very useful website when it comes to converting Json to PlainOldJavaObjects. You just copy paste the Json response select Gson as annotation style and you're golden. You can try it.

Additional code for second object:

```
public class Json {

private String id;

private String name;

private String description;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}
```

JSON should look something like this.

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "id": "11111",
            "name": "dsfafds",
            "description": "sdfadfas"
        }
     ,

        {
            "id": "11111",
            "name": "dsfafds",
            "description": "sdfadfas"
        }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "Json to Pojo" don't work with my json :(. The main problem is that each filed is separate object

Comment: Are you sure you are copying it correctly? You need to put the json correctly otherwise it can't find anything.

Comment: You are right, I have not correct json, thanks a lot!

Comment: I have updated my answer. Your Json should look something like this. I tried it like this and Json to Pojo gave me results.

Comment: Unfortunately it not work with gson, I received list of object, for each field, gson created separate object so I have a lot of object where there is only one field

Comment: This is because your Json is structured that way. It's a list of lists. You don't need the extra brackets " [ "..." ] " for every object. If you remove those and try again you'll have a list of your objects. I have updated the answer above to reflect this comment. You can give it a try with this JSON, hope it helps.

Comment: I can't, it is server side and it is impossible to change it, that is why I am looking for solution